Adding an IIS Self-Signed Certificate to a Windows Container for a legacy ASP.NET MVC application
I am developing a Windows container for my legacy ASP.NET MVC application (on .NET 4.8) and have successfully built and deployed it using Docker. However, I am facing issues when trying to add a self-signed SSL certificate to enable HTTPS for the IIS site inside the container. Despite multiple attempts, I haven't been successful.
This is the Dockerfile I'm using:
# Use the official ASP.NET runtime image for .NET Framework 4.8
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

# Copy the ASP.NET application files
COPY Macs.FrontEnd/. .

# Copy the existing certificate into the container
COPY certificates/exmaple.pfx C:/certificates/exmaple.pfx

# Set permissions for IIS to access the application files
RUN cmd.exe /c "icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot /grant \"IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)RX\" /T"
RUN cmd.exe /c "icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot /grant \"IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)RX\" /T"

# Import the existing certificate using a SecureString
RUN powershell -Command " \
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'SecurePwdGoesHere' -Force -AsPlainText; \
    Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath 'C:\certificates\exmaple.pfx' -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $securePassword \
"

# Get the certificate thumbprint and store it in a file
RUN powershell -Command " \
    $thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.Subject -match 'exmaple.macs.local' }).Thumbprint; \
    Set-Content -Path C:\certificates\cert-thumbprint.txt -Value $thumbprint \
"

# Read the thumbprint from the file and bind it to IIS using netsh
RUN powershell -Command " \
    $thumbprint = Get-Content -Path C:\certificates\cert-thumbprint.txt; \
    netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=$thumbprint appid='{00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}' \
"

# Expose HTTP and HTTPS ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

I used following command to generate IIS self sign certificate
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "example.macs.local" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(1)
# Export the certificate to a .pfx file
$certPath = "$env:USERPROFILE\example.pfx"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'SecurePwdGoesHere' -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath $certPath -Password $securePassword
Write-Host "Certificate generated and exported to: $certPath"

Can anyone provide insights or guidance on what might be causing the problem and how to correctly add a self-signed SSL certificate to an IIS-hosted site inside a Windows container? Your help would be greatly appreciated!
